# What is Dialyzer with succ_typings false?

Tags: types, erlang, dialyzer

I thought Dialyzer was a tool for checking success typings. However, its public API has a succ_typings false option. Rebar3's Dialyzer provider exposes this via the [`--succ-typings false` command line option](http://rebar3.org/docs/commands/).

What is the difference between running Dialyzer with and without this option?

The docs are [silent on this question](https://erlang.org/doc/man/dialyzer.html).

Answer (score 3):

Looks like the previous analysis type was called [`dataflow`](http://www.erlang.se/workshop/2003/paper/p56-nystrom.pdf) (Nyström, 2003) and later success typing (`succ_typings`) [was introduced](https://www.it.uu.se/research/group/hipe/dialyzer/RELEASE_NOTES).

The dataflow soft typing is discontinued as of [Erlang/OTP R12B-2](https://www.it.uu.se/research/group/hipe/dialyzer/RELEASE_NOTES), see:

> - Dialyzer's analysis is from now on exclusively based on success typings.
>   In particular, support for options `--old_style` and `--dataflow` has been
>   discontinued.